# Accessing elements of XAML file in .cs file in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I am creating a UI and I have two XAML files and two cs files:

`Main.xaml`
`Library.xaml`

`Main.xaml.cs`
`Library.xaml.cs`

I have declared a Button in `Library.xaml` and given a Name **`my_button`** and I want to access that Button in Main.cs.

How can I do that?

`Library.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <ControlTemplate>
      <Button x:Name=my_button Content="Click"></Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: show the xaml where we can see how these 2 xaml's relate .

Comment: Maybe TemplateBinding and CommandBinding could solve your problem, instead of assigning the button's name and accessing it from main.

Answer (score -1):

If these 2 are independent (etc. Library isn't a child of Main), then the simpliest solution would be to inject the object via constructor or property at the point you are creating a Library. If the Libary is inside Main, then you can give the x:Name attribute to the Library in your xaml and then access like this.library.my_button.

Another solution is to use a static messaging service class.